# How can I print the value of ostream variable by stdstring?

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream, stdstring, ostream

I tried to print the value that exists in the ostream variable by convert to string, and then to print the string instead the ostream argument.
But it's not working.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>

using std::ostream;

typedef std::basic_stringstream<char> stringstream;
class X {
public:
    int y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X x) {
    return os << x.y;
}

int main() {
    X x;
    x.y = 5;

    stringstream ss;
    ostream output(nullptr);
    output << x;
    ss << output.rdbuf();
    std::string myString = ss.str();

    std::cout << x << std::endl; // 5
    std::cout << "myString.c_str() :" << std::endl;
    std::cout << myString.c_str() << std::endl; // nothing.
}
```

How can I fix this problem so that I will get at `myString.c_str()` the appropriate output?

the output in `std::cout << myString.c_str() << std::endl;` line is "" (empty string - nothing) , and I want that it's will be `5` too (namely, the `output` in type of `char*`)..

Comment: You don't have to use `.c_str()` in order to be able to `cout` it.

Comment: @Carl If you mean that I need to do : `std::cout << myString << std::endl;` , it's not working too (I still get empty string - "").

Comment: Do you need the extra layer of indirection through `output`. Can't you just do `ss << x;`. Then it works as expected.

Comment: @Carl Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: Instead of going: `output << x; ss << output.rdbuf();` you can simply do `ss << x;` and read directly into the stringstream.

Comment: @Carl The thing is, this allows text addition to the `output` ostream to be done before the call to `rdbuf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Quted from  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/rdbuf/

**std::ofstream::rdbuf**

> Returns a pointer to the internal filebuf object.
>
> Notice however, that this is not necessarily the same as the currently
>   associated stream buffer (returned by ios::rdbuf).

Answer (score 0):

When you construct an `ostream` object, you should specify the buffer, i.e. where to output. You can construct `output` as follows:

```
std::stringbuf buf; 
std::ostream output(&buf);
```

Anyway, as [Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5834077/carl) suggested in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782912/how-can-i-print-the-value-of-ostream-variable-by-stdstring#comment88572588_50782912), you don't need the intermediate object `output`, and simply do

```
ss << x;
```